# Use Row of Data Frame as X-Axis in Plotly Line Chart

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-express

I am trying to make a plotly line chart that shows team member progression with the following excel data:

[image]

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to set the team member names as the color for the lines, the x-axis as the months, and the y-axis as the numeric values. Closest I've gotten is a blank graph, and I've tried about 400 combinations of parameters for

```
px.line(
        df,
        color="Team_Member",
        x = "the row of months... something with iloc maybe?",
        y = df.columns,
        title="Average Estimated Daily Working Hours by Team Member"
       )
```

Comment: An [official example](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#style-line-plots) would be helpful. I think it can be achieved by setting the data you want to set for each x-axis and y-axis as a list of column data in the data frame.